# Como ordenar um dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando ordenar os valores numéricos de um dataset em ordem crescente utilizando :

```py
df.sort_values(by=['radius_mean'], axis=0)
```

Mas eu gostaria de ordenar todas as colunas em ordem crescente e não ordenar em função de somente uma das colunas , alguém teria algum método que resolve-se?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma demanda estranha! Teoricamente uma tabela com registros por linhas devem manter os dados das colunas de cada linha. Da forma que você está querendo, você tratará cada coluna como dados independentes.

Mas indo para solução, você poderia usar o seguinte código:

```
for c in df.columns:
     df[c] = sorted(df.loc[:,c])
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda , funcionou , !  volte sempre +) kkk